# Monkeypatching logging.Logger -- how do arguments work?

Tags: python, logging, monkeypatching

I have a logging class that I've written that I like to use. It looks like this:

```
class EasyLogger(object):
    SEP = " "

    def __init__(self, logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)):
        self.logger = logger

    def _format_str(self, *args):
        return self.SEP.join([str(a) for a in args])

    def debug(self, *args):
        self.logger.debug(self._format_str(*args))

    .... repeated for the other logging methods, like info, warning, etc....

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.logger, name)
```

This gives me syntax like:

```
LOG.debug("some_variable: ", some_variable)
```

which I like. I don't want to inherit from `logging.Logger` because composition is better than inheritance and I don't really want to mess around with builtin classes like that.

My format string looks like:

```
LOGGING_FMT = "<%(filename)s:%(lineno)s(%(levelname)s) - %(funcName)s() >"\
                        "%(message)s"
```

but this doesn't work, because the line numbers and function name always report as something inside `easylogger.py` rather than the calling function.

I've fixed this issue by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957858/how-to-write-own-logging-methods-for-own-logging-levels) fantastic answer and monkeypatching the `findCaller` method of `EasyLogger.logger`, which looks like this:

```
def __init__(self, logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)):
    self.logger = logger
    # Ugly, ugly, ugly dirty hack to fix line numbers
    self.logger.findCaller = find_caller_monkeypatch
```

This works, but I'm confused. I originally defined `find_caller_monkeypatch` with the following signature:

```
def find_caller_monkeypatch(self):
```

(the body of the function is copy+pasted from the answer that's linked). However, this causes an error:

```
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1262, in _log
    fn, lno, func = self.findCaller()
TypeError: find_caller_monkeypatch() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Removing `self` as an argument to `find_caller_multipatch` fixes the error, but I'm confused: why isn't `find_caller_monkeypatch` getting `self` as an argument when it's called as `self.findCaller()`? Do methods only get `self` as a parameter if they're defined inside of the class?

The following snippet is a smaller example of the same issue:

```
In [7]: class Foo(object):
   ...:     def say_hi(self):
   ...:         print "Hello World"
   ...:         

In [8]: def say_bye_self(self): print "Goodbye world"

In [9]: def say_bye(): print "Goodbye world"

In [10]: foo = Foo()

In [11]: foo.say_hi()
Hello World

In [12]: foo.say_hi = say_bye_self

In [13]: foo.say_hi()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-10baea358e0b> in <module>()
----> 1 foo.say_hi()

TypeError: say_bye_self() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

In [14]: foo.say_hi = say_bye

In [15]: foo.say_hi()
Goodbye world
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

You can Monkeypatch on the class

```
Foo.say_hi = say_bye_self
foo = Foo()
foo.say_hi()
```

Or you can Monkeypatch an instance

```
import types
foo.say_hi = types.MethodType(say_bye_self, foo)
```

Comment: Interesting. But why isn't the monkeypatched function getting `self` as a parameter? I thought that `object.function()` always passed `object` as an argument to `function`.